# Blending: do not sum transparent faces

Tags: opengl, transparency, blending

I have several transparent cubes in a row close to each other. How to make final frame do not sum colors of Front cube with Back cube?

[image]

Which blend mode should I use? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't render those faces if you don't want to see them.

Comment: Do you mean do not render using some openGl mode or should I build mesh without this faces before render?

Comment: There is no general opengl mode which would remove these faces.

Comment: If you do this in two passes and use the depth buffer, you can reject those interior faces. Only the outer-most faces will be blended. You'll have to mess around with color writes between passes, but the basic procedure is outlined in an answer I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942407/why-is-opengl-gldepthfunc-not-working). _Ignore the parts about drawing with line/fill mode though, that's irrelevant._

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, thanks! Theoretically, will these 2 passes cost like 2 "common" passes (like pass used for default solid render)?

Comment: A depth-only pass is pretty quick on modern hardware, so the first pass (depth enabled, color disabled) should be less expensive than a regular render pass (depth enabled, color enabled). In fact, you can turn depth writes off on the second pass, and that might also improve performance.

Comment: You might want to try out GL20.glBlendEquationSeparate();